# Devops isn't outputting static content in the pipeline

Tags: npm, azure-devops, nuxt.js, npm-run

I have a repo in devops with a pipeline that i'm unable to configure correctly.

My objective is to run a custom npm command: `npm run generate`

With the result being that the vue application bakes out the html, css and js into a specific folder in the solution.

When run locally using the command above it works as expected and outputs a wwwroot/dist folder with the vue application in the form of html, css, js files.

However when I execute the pipeline using the same approach the artifact doesn't include that output. So it either is working as expected but the output isn't being included in the artifact, or it's not actually building the output.

The relevant parts of the pipeline config are:

```
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.9.0'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\app'
    verbose: false

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\app'
    customCommand: 'run generate'
    verbose: true

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'redacted'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)" /p:TransformConfigFile=true /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
```

I'm not seeing anything of consequence in terms of errors in the logs.

The npm command is in turn using nuxt to generate the output.  The confusing part is that it's working locally when I execute it, just no in the pipeline.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there additional tasks in the pipeline below? I'm not seeing the `PublishArtifacts` task.

Comment: @AlexanderSchmidt - I've added the balance of the pipeline commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this task before the `PublishBuildArtifacts`:

```yaml
- task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: Copy scripts to staging
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\app
      contents: '*.*'
      targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

and run the pipeline again. If the folder is present then the step `VSBuild@1` is not adding to the output obviously. If the web app is .NET core try to use

```yaml
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Publish
    inputs:
      command: publish
      publishWebProjects: True
      arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: True
```

Comment: Thanks - I've added the first task you suggested however the only way I know how to test if it worked is to download the artifact (so correct me if wrong). When I do so, the zip file doesn't contain the output.  I also modified it to reference the expected output folder '\wwwroot' but again no luck.

Comment: I'm confused. When you add the `CopyFiles` job, does the artifact directory contain any of the generated files?

Comment: No - nothing additional gets added to the artifact.

Comment: That would mean that the step 2 (NPM build) does not output anything. You could try to add step with Bash to just output the ´$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\app´ content using ´ls´ and let it run in that directory after the NPM build.

Answer (score 0):

As it worked out, the resolution here had to do with the configuration of the nuxt.config.js.  The generate command was running a server side process in generating the output, which required that the endpoints used in the application through axios were available during the build and generate.

However the endpoints in this instance were only available through our internal VPN (for development) and so when attempting to run the build or generate it was failing, though not reporting much in the output other than some overflow errors (after some fiddling to at least get these errors showing).

I modified the nuxt configuration by adding this to the config:

```
  ssr: false,
```

This stopped the server side processing which wasn't required for our application and the generate command starting working as expected.